# tf.boolean_mask not accepting the axis argument

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, yolo

Here is my code:

```
 44     scores = tf.boolean_mask(box_class_scores,filtering_mask,axis=-1)
 45     boxes = tf.boolean_mask(boxes,filtering_mask,axis=-1)
 46     classes = tf.boolean_mask(box_classes,filtering_mask,axis=-1)
```

Error, I'm getting:

> TypeError: boolean_mask() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'

The `tf.boolean_mask()` is not accepting the axis argument but is a valid argument as can be seen in the documentation: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/boolean_mask

[image]

Comment: you might want to check if your tensorflow version is matching the documentation you are looking at

Comment: @SUSHANTH TIWARY  Are you doing deep learning specializatiion course. I am facing the same issue from 2 days. Please help me how to resolve that

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the `axis` argument from the function , it will work .The error you are getting will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

As @syltruong has pointed out, check if the version of Keras you're using matches the documentation. Right now, the documentation uses version 2.2.4.

On a side note @Ganesh and @Sushant, you don't actually need to use the axis parameter for that particular piece of code in the Deep Learning Specialization.